# Is there a regulation about the shape of the posts of a football goal?

Tags: football, equipment

I mostly saw posts of football goals with a circular bases, but sometimes I saw posts (and crossbars) with very square basis.

```
| Is there a regulation about it?
```

It seems to me that the poles with square base are dangerous for a collision with a player.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As with much of this stuff, this is explicitly covered in the [Laws of the Game](http://www.fifa.com/mm/Document/FootballDevelopment/Refereeing/02/36/01/11/LawsofthegamewebEN_Neutral.pdf). In this case, Law 1 The Field of Play, Goalposts (page 9):

> The goalposts and crossbar [...] must be square, rectangular, round or elliptical in shape and must not be dangerous to players.

Given that the Laws explicitly allow square or rectangular posts, I don't think you're going to be able to make an argument that they are disallowed just because you think they're dangerous.